# Converting From Early Binding to Late Binding

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, late-binding

## Update # 2

I changed the values of the txtbox and submitbtns with a `(0)` (and also tried `(1)` as well), no changes.

And I also need to note that the Button has a different name and I updated accordingly here as well.

```
Dim TBox As String          'Name of object textbox to have value changed in
Dim TBtn As String          'Name of object button to be pressed
    TBox = "masked1"
    TBtn = "button"

If Not IE Is Nothing Then
    Set txtBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)(0)
    Set submitBtn = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBtn)(0)

    txtBox.Value = tVal
    submitBtn.Click
End If
```

## UPDATE # 1

So, things look promising with the suggestion provided by @cyboashu. However, I still cannot get my txtbox to update to the `value = tVal` (String).

```
Dim oShell      As Object
Dim oWin        As Object
Dim IE          As Object
Dim lTotlWin    As Long
Dim lCtr

Debug.Print Time & " --- IE Objects & Values ---"       ' Debugger Section
Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Debug.Print Time & " [obj ] oShell..: " & oShell    ' Debug oShell
Set oWin = oShell.Windows()
    Debug.Print Time & " [obj ] oWin....: " & oWin      ' Debug oWin

lTotlWin = oWin.Count - 1   '/ Starts with zero
Debug.Print Time & " [long] lTotlWin: " & lTotlWin      ' Debug lTotlWin

For lCtr = 0 To lTotlWin
    If UCase(oWin.Item(lCtr).FullName) Like "*IEXPLORE.EXE" Then
        Set IE = oWin.Item(lCtr)
    End If
Next
Debug.Print Time & " [obj ] IE......: " & IE
If Not IE Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Found and hooked!!"
End If

Dim TBox As String          'In the event the textbox's name changes for some reason
    TBox = "masked1"

If Not IE Is Nothing Then
    Set txtBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)
    Debug.Print Time & " [obj ] txtbox..: " & txtbox
    Set submitBtn = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)
    Debug.Print Time & " [obj ] submitBtn:" & submitBtn

    txtBox.Value = tVal
    submitBtn.Click
End If

Set shellwins = Nothing

Debug.Print Time & "- - - END SUB - - -" & E
```

End Sub

(Debugger values if anyone cares)..

```
2:44:11 PM --- IE Objects & Values ---
2:44:11 PM [long] lTotlWin: 5
2:44:11 PM [obj ] IE......: Internet Explorer
2:44:11 PM - - - END SUB - - -
```

Comment: What does your current (non-working) late binding code look like: the code you posted looks like the early binding version, so what progress have you made so far?

Comment: @TimWilliams I have updated my question to show what I have now

Comment: Do you get the "hooked" messagebox ? `IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)` returns a collection of nodes (note the "s" in Elements), not a single element.  You need something like `Set txtBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)(0)` to get a reference to the first member of that collection.

Comment: Yes, I did receive that msgbox prompt. Would would I do to change the textbox in the `class = masked1`?

Comment: edited my comment above...

Comment: @TimWilliams Updated my results in the original question (because I left out the button's name). But after adding the `(0)` or a `(1)`, it still did not update the field in IE. I confirmed doing a search by the class name there are no other classes with the name.

Comment: Can't offer anything else without a URL

Comment: I have resolved the issue by adding the site to my trusted sites and restarting IE. I believe it may have something to do with the site being in "Protected Mode". Thank you so much for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get object won't work here.

What MS says about it : https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/239470

> Calling GetObject to get a running ActiveX object on a client system
>   would be a large security risk because any running object on the
>   system could be accessed without direct user permission, and is
>   therefore not allowed by Internet Explorer. There is no way to change
>   this behavior, either through code or manually by an end user.

Try this :

```
Sub testIELateBinding()

    Dim oShell              As Object
    Dim oWin                As Object
    Dim IE                  As Object
    Dim lTotlWin            As Long
    Dim lCtr


    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set oWin = oShell.Windows()

    lTotlWin = oWin.Count - 1 '/ Starts with zero

    For lCtr = 0 To lTotlWin
        If UCase(oWin.Item(lCtr).FullName) Like "*IEXPLORE.EXE" Then
            Set IE = oWin.Item(lCtr)
        End If
    Next


    If Not IE Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Found and hooked!!"
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That seems to be about calling GetObject *from within IE*.  I don't think that's the case here

Comment: When I tested GetObject on my side, I got the error message saying, can't create ActiveX object, so I thought it makes sense. ActiveX initialization is being blocked. But you never know :)

Comment: @cyboashu Debugger values `2:25:25 PM [long] lTotlWin: 5` & `2:25:25 PM [obj ] IE......: Internet Explorer`. I received your msgbox prompt that it was hooked, however, it is not updating my objects `Set txtBox = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName(TBox)` w/ `txtBox.Value = Phn`