# Excel VBA - GetElementByID giving Object Variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba

so I'm definitely a fish out of water with having VBA access things outside of the Excel I'm running it in, and I'm pretty stuck with this one.

I'm trying to automate filling out a form in IE (the form is on a pop-up window that must already be open and can only be opened in IE, so I can't create a window then navigate to it or use Chrome). From what I've searched the closest I have come is something that can search through open windows and check the titles for something that matches.

```
Debug.Print (wind.Document.Title)
```

works fine, but

```
wind.Document.GetElementByID("x").Value = "BOA"
```

gives me a run-time error (Object variable or With block variable not set)

```
 Dim noURL As Boolean
noURL = True
Dim windDoc As Object

If url_T.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "No URL provided"
    Exit Sub
Else
    For Each wind In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
        If wind = "Internet Explorer" Then
            If InStr(UCase(wind.Document.Title), UCase(url_T.Value)) <> 0 Then
                noURL = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next wind

    If noURL = True Then
        MsgBox "No window located"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

wind.Visible = True
Debug.Print (wind.Document.Title)
wind.Document.GetElementByID("txtIncidentDescription").Value = "BOA"
```

Here's the DOM view of the element I'm after (does anyone know a better way of copying this view in IE?)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiY7U.jpg

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859727/vba-choosing-specific-tab-on-internet-explorer/38860882#38860882

Comment: Must already be open or is already open?

Comment: If you are starting out in web scraping I'd recommend learning Chrome extensions (which are now portable to Microsoft Edge)  You'll need to learn javascript but there is a huge advantage in being embedded in the browser's process than than trying to script from a separate (Excel.exe) process.  Also VBA can only interact with Internet Explorer which is to be trashed (eventually).

Comment: @TimWilliams As far as I can tell, that's just a more convoluted version of what I've already got. I tested it and got the same result.
`IE.Navigate "www.google.com"` works fine, `Debug.Print (IE.Document.Title)` works fine.

It must be an issue with GetElementID. This is where I'm grabbing the ID:

`<INPUT tabIndex=1 id=txtIncidentDescription style="WIDTH: 170px" maxLength=255 name=txtIncidentDescription origvalue="">`

Comment: Can you share a URL?  Looks like the document has frames, so are you targetting a specific frame when you try to find the window?  I'm not sure that's going to work...

Comment: @TimWilliams I can't share a URL; it's run on an internal server. I don't know about frames.

Answer (score 0):

Tim Williams code works, then you have to burrow down way further. You want to use

```
<tr>
```

in your case, then add the selection Dim, but I am just learning, Tim take us from there, me and the OP want the same thing as in my other post,  [Extract scrape after browser is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56613483/extract-scrape-after-browser-is-open)