# How to set an already open web page back into focus via code after an error

Tags: html, excel, vba

This should be simple and I've tried many of the examples posted on S/O and elsewhere but I can't seem to get it to work. Maybe a syntax error or I'm missing something else.
Here's my code setup to start me off

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://abcde"
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Set htmlDoc = IE.Document
```

From here I open the page, enter ID & Password via code, click a number of buttons and continue navigating a few pages into it and since I'm doing some trial and error, I ultimately get an error.
The page I want, maybe it's now  "https://qwert" is still open, visible and I can still work on it directly but, of course, I can't continue with my VBA code on it.

How do I get Excel to be able to act upon that open web page via code so that I don't have to start over from the beginning?

Thanks for any help someone might be able to offer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859727/vba-choosing-specific-tab-on-internet-explorer/38860882#38860882

Comment: The question that you referenced was one of the ones that I had previously tried but unsuccessfully. Since you referenced it again, I went back to figure out what I was doing wrong with it and got it to work for me so thank you, Tim.
My issue was with using the entire URL 

GetIE("https://a810-dobnow.nyc.gov/Publish/Cranes/index.html#/dashBoard"'

when all I really needed was 

GetIE("https://a810-dobnow.nyc.gov/Publish/Cranes/" & "*"

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out.